# How to get ListBox Item height

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, listbox

Here I have a `ListBox`:

```
 <ListBox Name="listbox1"   ItemsSource="{Binding Area}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <DockPanel  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">
                                <TextBox PreviewTextInput="minMaxPreviewInput" IsReadOnly="{Binding AutoChange}" Text="{Binding MinIntValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="30" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Minimum Value" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">
                                <TextBox PreviewTextInput="minMaxPreviewInput" IsReadOnly="{Binding AutoChange}" Text="{Binding MaxIntValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="30" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Maximum Value" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AreaName}" FontSize="20" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock Text=":" FontSize="20" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Start}" FontSize="20" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                <CheckBox FlowDirection="RightToLeft" DockPanel.Dock="Right" IsChecked="{Binding AutoChange, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                    <TextBlock FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Text="Auto-Change:" />
                                </CheckBox>

                            </DockPanel>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="5">
                                <Canvas Name="canvas1" >
                                    <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" />
                                    </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                                    <Polyline Points="{Binding SegmentPoints}" Stroke="Black"    StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                </Canvas>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Everything works as great. I'm having problem accessing the `Canvas` size. How can I access it? `Listbox.ActualHeight` and `ListBox.ActualWidth` are bigger than the `Canvas`, and I need to get the Canvas exact size.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Access how and from where? Via a relative binding in XAML? Directly in code?

Comment: Direclty in the code, in MainWindow.xaml.cs. The above code is from MainWindow.xaml

Comment: As you've got fairly complex binding going already - why do you need to access it in codebehind?

Comment: Canvas is used to display sensor values in real time. Canvas size is adjuctable, since it is in a Grid, and the Grid Columon is sized *8. For displayinging the values, I need to compute the values X, and Y coordinates, and for that, I need the Canvas size, to match it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to base the value of other bound values on the `Canvas` size, use `OneWayToSource` mode on a `Binding` for `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` to some properties on your ViewModel.

This will push the values from the control into your `ViewModel` allowing you to adjust the values in `SegmentPoints` so that they are scaled correctly according to the `Canvas` size.